# mysql configuration file on centos 7

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on centos 7 on office, I expected it would have configuiration file located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but I spotted directly under `/etc`.

is it possible to find out using the mysql cli the configuration file in use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configuring-mysql-server-on-centos/) for details. The article discusses the default configuration file scan order.

But you could also specify the `--defaults-file` when starting mysql, please use `ps -ef |grep mysql` or similar command to check. On my machine, the output like this(suse12):

```
ps -ef |grep mysql
mysql   968      1  0 Apr27 ?  00:46:36 ./mysqld --defaults-file=/export/home/mysql/mysql-8.0.11/my.cnf --user=mysql
root  71136  65599  0 11:45 pts/0  00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: only that specific file is not there  i.e. `mysqld --defaults-file`  is not there

Comment: if defaults-file is not specified, then mysql will use the default config file scan order.